# bwa mem used. 'mem' being shown as unrecognized command

Tags: qiime

I am using Virtual Box and trying to run bwa on the terminal. To align left and right reads against the reference I used 'bwa mem'  it showed me an error stating "unrecognized command 'mem'". Is there a way I can get it separately or another way out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an old version of bwa and you may want to install a newer one as bra mem is definitely a command in the latests version of the software.